# How to search from a TextBox and fill specific columns of a DataGridView from a SQL database?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sqldatareader

I am trying to search by itemcode provided in TextBox1.  I have manually created headers in the designer for DataGridView.  My code successfully queries the database but appends the additional columns to the full results returned by the query.

My code:

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

    On Error Resume Next

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true")
        Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("select itemcode As 'Item Code', item,qty As Quantity, weight as Weight from stockdata Where itemcode = @itemcode;", cn)

            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", TextBox1.Text)
            cn.Open()

            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(dr)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@weight", SqlDbType.VarChar)

                With cmd2
                    row.Cells(1).Value = .Parameters("@item").Value
                    row.Cells(2).Value = .Parameters("@qty").Value
                    row.Cells(2).Value = .Parameters("@weight").Value
                End With
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use On Error Resume Next, it's only good for backwards compatibility.  You should be catching errors with Try/Catch blocks.

Comment: Why are you adding item, qty and weight as parameters?  I think the issue you're having is you're loading the entire result set into DataGridView1 and then appending item, qty and weight to that table again.

Comment: i want to fill that data in already made columns in datagridview but it is generating new columns and fill data in that columns.

Comment: Why not just get rid of the columns you added and use the columns provided by the DataTable?

Comment: This is a perfect example of what happens when someone tries to write code without knowing what the code actually has to do. You execute a query and populate a `DataTable` with the results and then bind the `DataTable` to the grid. What exactly is the loop after that supposed to be doing?

Comment: If you have added columns yourself and you want to bind then you need to set the `DataPropertyName` of those columns to tell them what to bind to.  If you don't do that then new columns will be created by default when you bind. That said, if the result will be the same, just let the columns be created when you bind. Only create the columns in the designer if you need something specific that won't happen automatically, e.g. a combo box instead of a text box, or you want to bind in the designer too.

Comment: Your For loop makes no sense. First you add Parameters to a command that does not use those parameters and you keep adding them again for each iteration of the loop. Next you take the value of those parameters (which is nothing) and assign them to cells in your Grid. You are assigning to existing rows, overwriting them.

Comment: i have asked question because it is new thing for me. i know that my for syntax is useless. so i posted this question to forum so that someone guide me how to do this type of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you're trying to accomplish something like this.  But as others have pointed out there's better ways to actually bind your data to the grid.

```
    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true")
            Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("select itemcode As 'Item Code', item,qty As Quantity, weight as Weight from stockdata Where itemcode = @itemcode;", cn)

                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", TextBox1.Text)
                cn.Open()

                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

                'Read each line
                While dr.Read()

                    Using record As New DataGridViewRow

                        'Get the individual items you want to return
                        Dim item As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell With {.Value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("item"))}
                        Dim qty As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell With {.Value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("qty"))}
                        Dim weight As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell With {.Value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("weight"))}

                        'Add each of those cells to the row
                        record.Cells.Add(item)
                        record.Cells.Add(qty)
                        record.Cells.Add(weight)

                        'Add the entire row to the DataGridView
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(record)
                    End Using
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
```

Comment: Since this code was in a Button.Click event in the OP, I don't think it is a Console Application.

Comment: Agreed but I don't have any idea how he's capturing other errors.  I suppose a MsgBox or something is more general and may fit his use-case but it's still a million times better than On Error Resume Next.

Comment: thanks Nathan Champion for helping me. your code is working very fine without any error.